# Grails 3 : Custom tags output showing as a string in front end

Tags: groovy, grails3

I have created one custom tag lib class in my application that is shown below.

```
class CustomTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
    static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'html']]
    def selectList = { attrs ,body ->
        try{
            String servName=attrs.service
            String servMethod=attrs.method
            ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext())
            def myservice=ctx."${servName}"
//            def myservice = Holders.getApplicationContext().getBean( servName );

            attrs.from = myservice.invokeMethod(servMethod,null);

            out << g.select( attrs )
        }catch(Exception e){
            println("Exception in CustomTagLib in method selectList:"+e)
        }
    }
}
```

but the output is showing as a string as shown below. 
[image]

Please give any suggestion to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding your rendering code to a template e.g.

```
def from = myservice.invokeMethod(servMethod,null);

out << render( template: "/templates/dropdown",
         model: [from: from] )
```

Then in `/views/templates/_dropdown.gsp`

```
<g:select from="${from}" />
```

You can of course pass in more arguments to the model.